# Thousands of Inserts and I having duplicated values, Why?

Tags: php, android, mysql, laravel, post

I have an application that is a car parking system, my clients use it a lot to send to my database entries of data from the car.

here is the code to send to my server :

```
 public void sendEntradaRotativaDataToServer(String url){

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setMessage("Processando entrada..");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    json.addProperty("placa",  entradaObj.getPlaca());
    json.addProperty("dataemissao",  entradaObj.getDataemissao());
    json.addProperty("tipo",   entradaObj.getTipo());
    json.addProperty("valor",  entradaObj.getValor());
    json.addProperty("area",   entradaObj.getArea().getId());
    json.addProperty("observacao",  entradaObj.getObservacao());
    json.addProperty("user_id",  entradaObj.getUser_id());

    Ion.with(getActivity())
            .load(url)
            .setTimeout(5000)
            .setJsonObjectBody(json)
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {

                    if (e != null) {

                        newMsgWarn("Atenção","Não foi possível fazer uma conexão por favor tente novamente");

                        if(pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()){
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    } else {

                        success   = result.get(TAG_SUCCESS).getAsInt();
                        message   = result.get(TAG_MESSAGE).getAsString();

                        entradaObj.set_id(result.get("entradaid").getAsString());

                        (new SyncEntrada()).execute(new String[0]);

                        if(pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()){
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    }

                }


            });

}
```

it is a simple post request with the Ion library and this is the code on the server ( i'm using laravel on the project ) :

```
public function insertDataRotativa(Request $request) {


    if(isset($request)) {

        $dataentradaini = Carbon::parse($request->input('dataemissao'));           
        $evento   = $this->mdUtil->getEventByDataEmissao($dataentradaini);

        if (!empty($evento)) {

          foreach ($evento as $value) {  

              $this->mdEntrada                 = new Entrada; 
              $this->mdEntrada->placa          = $request->input('placa');
              $this->mdEntrada->created_at     = $dataentradaini;
              $this->mdEntrada->updated_at     = $dataentradaini;
              $this->mdEntrada->tipo           = $request->input('tipo');
              $this->mdEntrada->valor          = $request->input('valor');
              $this->mdEntrada->area           = $request->input('area');
              $this->mdEntrada->observacao     = $request->input('observacao');
              $this->mdEntrada->user_id        = $request->input('user_id');
              $this->mdEntrada->evento_id      = $value->id;    
              $this->mdEntrada->flag           = "U";                  
              $this->mdEntrada->save();

          }             

       }else {


              $this->mdEntrada                 = new Entrada; 
              $this->mdEntrada->placa          = $request->input('placa');
              $this->mdEntrada->created_at     = $dataentradaini;
              $this->mdEntrada->updated_at     = $dataentradaini;
              $this->mdEntrada->tipo           = $request->input('tipo');
              $this->mdEntrada->valor          = $request->input('valor');
              $this->mdEntrada->area           = $request->input('area');
              $this->mdEntrada->observacao     = $request->input('observacao');
              $this->mdEntrada->user_id        = $request->input('user_id');                 
              $this->mdEntrada->flag           = "U";                  
              $this->mdEntrada->save();


       }    

        $response["success"]             = 1;
        $response["message"]             = "Entrada efetuada com sucesso.TIPO:1";
        $response["entradaid"]           = $this->mdEntrada->id;

        return $response;       

}
```

I'm guessing that is the user that press so many times the button to send but I put a time to enable and not enable on the button that will not make many requests in the same time, here is the code for the button :

```
 sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


            YoYo.with(Techniques.BounceIn)
                    .duration(500)
                    .playOn(v.findViewById(R.id.entradabt));


            if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 3000){
                return;
            }
            mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            enviarEntrada();

        }
    });
```

Why am i having this kind of duplicate records? Any tips?

[image: here is the new image from database]

Here my schema

[image: my schema]

Comment: Is there a timestamp for each row? Is there a unique key (other than the primary key)? Edit your question and add the schema including indexes for the table.

Comment: thank you Sloan Tharasher.

Yes it have is the created_at and updated_at from laravel, and in the duplicated records are the same time.

I will put the image now

Comment: What about the rest of my questions?

Comment: Why the foreach? Are multiple rows being sent? Why aren't you checking for duplicates inside the foreach?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see. for your question about the key, no the only unique key is the id from table, i will put the schema on my main question. The foreach is because if the user want to put a event, but is always empty so the if(!empty(evento) is always true and the functio only execute the second code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Unique_Key*

Add a unique Key on Created_at, Updated_at and Placa Seeing as this might be the Unique identifier for this table. This prevent at exactly the same time insertions.

Also **check** if one request sends the SAME request multiple time and filter these out by PLACA (carplate?) (only 1 placa can be send in a single request).

**Might be handy?** 
If the same PLACA sends within 1 minute of paying the same request, ignore it.
(SQL Query filter, request all transactions within last minute and check if (carplate)placa is there). 

`result = SQL Query select all where placa is within 1 and or 2 min;
if(result is same PLACA as request){  return; and ignore request)`

Bit of pseudocode to help.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I see the unique key solution but i want to know where is the problem to duplicate you know? Is so many records that when the user press he insert two times?

Comment: Duplication comes from: inserting twice, where the inserting twice comes from is your code. somewhere in your code you insert the object twice.

Debug:
 foreach ($evento as $value) {  
$evento might be your culprit having twice the same data?

I need more information on "foreach ($evento as $value) {  " how can there be 2 times the same evento? Is what I think might be your question.
Which leads to : " $this->mdUtil->getEventByDataEmissao($dataentradaini);" 
No idea what this does.

Comment: Which ultimately might... (no idea)? lead to clicking to fast, check if you can simulate clicking to fast?

Comment: I will simulate the clicking fast and you look to int the foreach. I will explain this to you, in the system the user can create events and when the user inserts a data in that data range from a created event he insert the event in the record. I will debug and made this changes you are talking and return

Comment: Really thanks, i see where the error now, but you solution from unique id is great thanks!

Comment: Please select it as an appropiate answer, if it suits your solution.